# max and min not working on custom input component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend, pug

I developed a custom input component, when I try to use it on a parent component, default input attributes max and min do not work.
Here is my custom input element on the parent component

```
text-field(v-model="level" type="number" max="9" min="0" label="User Level" @beforeinput="onKeyup")
```

I saw that max and min not working that's why I wrote a function for the beforeInput event to prevent the user enter a number bigger than 9 and a string

```
 onKeyup(event: InputEvent) {
  const el = event.target as HTMLInputElement
  const value = +el.value
  console.log(value)
  if (value < 0 || value > 9) event.stopImmediatePropagation()
}
```

This function prevents users from entering string values but does not prevent users to enter a number bigger than 9. How can I fix this?

PS: I am using VueJS 3

Comment: What exactly should happen when a bigger value is entered? Should it stay max? Update the value in a watcher, you may not need befroeinput. Afair the way number inputs behave is specific to a browser and shouldn't be relied on

Comment: When a bigger number than 9 is entered it should stay as nine, in this way it should not user enter a bigger number

Comment: As I said, the behaviour is not determined and it may be possible that you won't be able to prevent it to be entered, just to fix a value immediately